# How to fix my url in spring framework

Tags: redirect, spring-mvc

I am working with Spring MVC3.2 and I have a registration form(http://my-server.com:8080/tracks/apks). Users post it to the server and the server will return error message when validation fails. But I got the error message from the server, the URL was different from what I wanted. Here is my code:

```
Web.xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>tracks</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


applicationContext.xml
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/apks")
public class ApkController {

@RequestMapping()
public ModelAndView index() {
    Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    modelMap.put("menus",   AdminService.getMenus("apks"));
    return new ModelAndView("apks", "model", modelMap);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView uploadApk(ApkInfo apkInfo, BindingResult bindingResult) {

     Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     modelMap.put("menus",   AdminService.getMenus("apks"));

     if (!fileExists(apk.getFileName())){

     modelMap.put("message", message); 
     }

     //Do something

     return new ModelAndView("apks", "model", modelMap);
}
```

After calling uploadApk, I expected http://my-server.com:8080/tracks/apks but The returned URL was http://my-server.com:8080/tracks/apks/insert.

What do I do to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What does 'The returned URL' mean?

You should access 'http://my-server.com:8080/apks/insert' to call 'uploadApk' method
cause you have

```
@RequestMapping("/apks")
```

on your controller and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

on your 'uploadApk' method.

---

How did you call the 'uploadApk' method?

I think that you should explain about it more to get an appropriate answer.

---

Since the url-pattern of servlet-mapping in your web.xml is '/',
you should remove '/tracks' in your url.

'tracks' is just a servlet name and not a servlet path.

So if you access to /tracks/apks/insert then you will got an 404 error.
Access to /apks/insert instead.

---

I guess that you may want a redirection after calling 'uploadApk' method
cause you attached 'redirect' tag on your question and used the word 'returned URL'. (Right?)

If my guess is right and you want to redirect the browser, then see [SpringMVC 3.2 Redirect View docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting).

Use below codes to redirect.

```
return new RedirectView("url-you-want");
```

or

```
return "redirect:url-you-want"
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of observation.

1. In your web.xml, do you specify context-paran, the servlet tracks and the listener?
2. Is context:component-scan enabled in your spring configuration file?
3. Use requestMapping at method level to map request to specific method.

Comment: Yes, I did all of them you mentioned. Other requests are working fine using requestmapping.